# PHP Permission denied in PrestaShop, not even chmod 777 working

Tags: php, permissions, filesystems, prestashop, chmod

i have problem with permissions.

I getting error

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(./public_html/shop/modules/dhlexpress/vendor/alfallouji/dhl_api/DHL/Entity/AM/GetQuote.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ./public_html/shop/modules/dhlexpress/vendor/alfallouji/dhl_api/vendor/autoloadManager/autoloadManager.php
```

I tried to set 777 recursive for whole dhlexpress folder. Also i tried to set 755 for folders and 644 for php files. Same error.

Owner of all files is ok.

Dump from ls -al for ./public_html/shop/modules/dhlexpress/vendor/alfallouji/dhl_api/vendor/autoloadManager/:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 master_qfremheqwx www-data  4096 Aug 23 07:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 master_qfremheqwx www-data  4096 Aug 23 07:29 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data 13945 Jan  6  2017 autoloadManager.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data  3755 Jan  6  2017 README.md
```

Dump from ls -al for ./public_html/shop/modules/dhlexpress/vendor/alfallouji/dhl_api/DHL/Entity/AM/ :

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 master_qfremheqwx www-data  4096 Aug 23 07:30 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 master_qfremheqwx www-data  4096 Aug 23 07:30 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data  2137 Jan  6  2017 GetQuote.php
```

I am hopeless. That permissions is killing me.

**EDIT:**

I also tried to set 777 for whole dhlexpress folder and sub-folders and files.

dhlexpress folder:

```
777 -rwxrwxrwx 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data 30134 Aug 23 21:51 dhlexpress.php
777 drwxrwxrwx 4 master_qfremheqwx www-data  4096 Aug 24 08:44 vendor
```

dhlexpress/vendor/alfallouji/dhl_api/DHL/Entity/AM/ folder:

```
777 -rwxrwxrwx 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data  2137 Jan  6  2017 GetQuote.php
```

dhlexpress/vendor/alfallouji/dhl_api/vendor/autoloadManager/ folder:

```
777 -rwxrwxrwx 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data 13945 Jan  6  2017 autoloadManager.php
777 -rwxrwxrwx 1 master_qfremheqwx www-data  3755 Jan  6  2017 README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

can you require file in 'modules' folder?
may be php don't have permission for 'modules' folder

Comment: Hi, that would be strange, in modules folder  are another 40 modules for prestashop which works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions from the modules folder or even better from the public_html, most servers works perfect with permissions as:

- Folders: 0755
- Files: 0644

Comment: Did, without efect. Strange is i have on same server another clone of this app with this same module. With same permissions, same owner, same group . And there its working.

Comment: Then maybe it could be something in the code directly in the module, since I suppose one store is in a sub-folder and the other not, because if they are cloned stores the only things that change are the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, done. Problem was in my autoloader from developer. I manualy make bunch of require_once and now its working

Answer (score 0):

For modules and files you need to put the rights in this form:

755 for directories/folders
644 for files